# What to write in mail having resume

Tags: professionalism, resume, human-resources, email, india

What should I write in an email when sending a resume to someone who has given me an email address and asked me to share my resume.

Extra question(trivial): Should I attach my resume as a PDF or DOC file? Thank you.

I have written the email like this

> Subject - Resume - Java Developer Position
>
> Hi Ankita, Please find attached a copy of my resume for Java Developer
> position at XYZ. Thank you so much, and I look forward to hearing back
> from you!
>
> Regards, YOURNAMEHERE.
>
> Software Developer
> Mobile: +91xxxxx
>
> Reply to: xxxxx@outlook.com

​

Comment: We don't need to see your contact details to answer this question.  You might want to remove those, unless you particularly like spam.

Comment: The one you've got is fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting resume in microsoft word doc format or a pdf generated by Latex?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/38601/submitting-resume-in-microsoft-word-doc-format-or-a-pdf-generated-by-latex)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What digital format to send resume/cover letter in?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2462/what-digital-format-to-send-resume-cover-letter-in)

Comment: Not a duplicate of the ones suggested. The question is more about what to write, not what to attach.

Comment: Why would you want to put a "`Reply to`" email address? Aren't you sending from that address?

Comment: @Mawg - I am using the same email, but many signatures I have seen those are using this option, that is why I too included. Thank you.

Comment: Reference the fact that **they asked you to send** them your resume/CV; mention the event or the date/time (e.g. *Nice to meet you yesterday afternoon, here's my resume as promised. We spoke about a Java position in the healthcare industry.*).  Near the top or in the subject.

Comment: @J.ChrisCompton - Nice points.. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your sample e-mail text is OK. I prefer to attach PDF, since it is difficult to modify it, especially by mistake.

Also, PDF guarantees the layout. MS Word does not.

However, if the company complains about the file type, provide it in a form suitable for the company.

Comment: Be careful as ATS sometimes does not pick up format from PDF properly

Comment: I am not sure what ATS is. I never had experience of PDF not being acceptable. You just made me curious.

Comment: @virolino https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicant_tracking_system

Comment: cool, tnx. I just learned something new ;)

Answer (score 2):

The only change I would make is to add your name to the subject line:

> Subject -  John Smith's Resume - Java Developer Position

Comment: Thank you. But If you see this mail in mobile or web, you would find sender name two times side by side, One is email name another one subject

Comment: That is a Solid Point.  Personally, I want my name in front of them as much as possible.  But I wouldnt argue the point.

Answer (score 2):

> What should I write in an email when sending a resume to someone who
>   has given me an email address and asked me to share my resume.

If the person you are sending the email to doesn't know you then take the opportunity to explain why you are sending them the email, the position you are interested in, who asked you to send them the email and resume.

If you only met the person one time, when they gave you their email address. You want to remind them where they met you: the job fair, the sporting event, the business conference.

If you know them well your introduction reminder can me less formal, but remember that other people may read it if the email gets forwarded. Expect that it will

In all situations you should also take a few sentences explain why your are interested in the position, and why they should consider you. This email is your cover letter. You want to give them a reason to open the resume, and a reason to consider you for the position.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Virolino, I generally prefer PDF, however every agency I have ever dealt with prefer MS Word, so they can remove your contact details and usually add their company logo to the top. (They do this to prevent the client contacting you directly and losing them commission, and also so that when your CV is seen internally by the client, their agency is top of mind).

The less scrupulous will sometimes change the details or even cut/paste a different candidate into it, but this is really rare, and in any case they can do it by pasting from the pdf.

**I'd go with latest version of MsWord.docx**.

I also have the Date Last Updated in very small font, top right. I find that helpful when someone calls me and I can ask what version they have.

I have in the past also included a copyright at the bottom. When I first saw someone else do that, I thought it was really stupid and pretentious, but changed my mind again a few years later.

Comment: Thank you for answer. You have taken bypass. My question is more of about email.

Comment: Sorry, Arvindraja. Your email looks fine, although I'm not based in India.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a cover letter, OP.  You write a letter explaining why you are a good fit for *this* company.  You remind the recipient that *they* asked to see your resume, where you met etc, so they don't think you're cold-contacting them.  Hopefully you had more than a 30-second conversation, so that you can pick up the topic and expand on it a bit to say something that sounds like you're halfway interested in their work.  Or you look at their website and manage to sound like you're halfway etc...

The fact that it's not a separate sheet of paper should not fool you to think this mail is not important.